# How to disable proxy cache when query string is empty?

Tags: nginx

With nginx I have

```
server {
  listen 1.2.3.4:80
  proxy_cache_valid       200 302 5m;
  location /  {
    try_files $uri @upstream;
    root $root;
  }
}
```

When I go `http://example.com/foobar` it generates a redirect to `http://example.com/foobar?filter_distance=50&...` which is visitor dependent so I would like to not cache this redirect. I need to bypass cache when the query string is empty. I am a bit lost because `location /foobar` will match both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added

```
map $request_uri $nocache {
  /foobar 1;
}
```

to the http section and

```
proxy_cache_bypass $nocache;
proxy_no_cache $nocache;
```

to the server section. This seems to be working.

Comment: Nice, I haven't used the `map` feature at all, so I didn't think of it.

Comment: It's hard to get into the nginx config headspace but once you are there, it's very neat: the default for `map` is the empty string and `proxy_no_cache` doesn't fire for empty strings.

Comment: Soooo... What exactly is the variable $nocache doing?

Comment: And what about HTTP section, in my site config I only have location and server - There is no http section 

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `proxy_cache_bypass` and `proxy_no_cache` directives like this:

```
set $nocache 0;

if ($arg_filter_distance = "") {
    set $nocache 1;
}

proxy_cache_bypass $nocache;
proxy_no_cache $nocache;
```

Definition of `proxy_no_cache` from [nginx documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_no_cache)

> Defines conditions under which the response will not be saved to a cache. If at least one value of the string parameters is not empty and is not equal to “0” then the response will not be saved:

Here we test if the filter_distance GET parameter is empty. If it is, we set $nocache to 1, and then the `proxy_cache_bypass` and `proxy_no_cache` directives will get active.

You can add other GET parameters similary, for example `$arg_filter_type`, if you have a `filter_type` GET parameter.

Comment: Sorry. You got it backwards. I need a proxy_no_cache if $arg_filter_distance is empty. The title of the question says so but I edited my question to emphasize.

Comment: See updated answer.

Comment: Sorry for the many questions... but I wanted to avoid `if` since http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil but I guess here it's OK?

Comment: It is a necessary evil in this spot.

Comment: `if` breaks `try_files`, however.